# Openshift: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

Tags: ruby, openshift

I am planning to deploy my django app via Openshift. While running `rhh setup` I get the error `An unexpected error occured: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8.

First try:

```
OpenShift can create and store a token on disk which allows to you to access the server
without using your password. The key is stored in your home directory and should be kept
secret.  You can delete the key at any time by running 'rhc logout'.
Generate a token now? (yes|no) yes
Generating an authorization token for this client ... An unexpected error occured: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

Second Try:

```
OpenShift can create and store a token on disk which allows to you to access the server
without using your password. The key is stored in your home directory and should be kept
secret.  You can delete the key at any time by running 'rhc logout'.
Generate a token now? (yes|no) yes
Generating an authorization token for this client ... lasts 30 days

Saving configuration to /home/username/.openshift/express.conf ... done

Your public SSH key must be uploaded to the OpenShift server to access code.  Upload
now? (yes|no)
yes

Since you do not have any keys associated with your OpenShift account, your new key will
be uploaded as the 'default' key.
An unexpected error occured: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same problem right now, but in the 3rd attempt the registration works